# Good way to store many nested JSON objects and arrays as data structure in Android SQLite?

Tags: java, android, json, sqlite, orm

Considering the below `JSON`, what would be the best way to store this into `SQLite`?

I am already parsing this with `Gson`, but wondering what would be a pain-free way to store this into `SQLite` and be able to retrieve it with no parsing issues.

I am already storing the `desc, deposit` objects as a `HashMaps`. My issue is the `lease` object. What would be an elegant way to store the `leasees` array?

Should I just create another `Leasee` object? And then serialize the ArrayList into a `Blob` for storage into the database?

```
{
  "name": "1",
  "desc": {
    "country": "1",
    "city": "1",
    "postal": "1",
    "street": "1",
    "substreet": "1",
    "year": 1,
    "sqm": 1
  },
  "owner": [
    "1"
  ],
  "manager": [
    "1"
  ],
  "lease": {
    "leasee": [
      {
        "userId": "1",
        "start": {
          "$date": 1420070400000
        },
        "end": {
          "$date": 1420070400000
        }
      }
    ],
    "expire": {
      "$date": 1420070400000
    },
    "percentIncrease": 1,
    "dueDate": 1
  },
  "deposit": {
    "bank": "China Construction Bank",
    "description": "Personal Bank Account USA"
  }
}
```

Comment: It's not recommended to store JSON in db, what happened if you want to update record or search for one? try to build db tables and store data in them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Storing everything in a BLOB ignores the benefit that a DB provides.

You have much of a relational database structure already described (however loosely) in the JSON:
Properties table with location and description info.
Persons table with names and contacts.
Roles table relating Properties and Persons (residents, managers, owners, service providers).
Leases table with terms related to Properties and Persons.
Payments table with payment info related to Leases.

You can manually write in the primary keys in your JSON, taking care to match those relationships between tables, then insert the resulting rows by processing that modified JSON. [Here's a link to SQLite doc](https://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html) on using INSERT with auto increment.

Comment: This sounds like a better structure. I guess to simplify it for instance, the `lease` object stored in the db would just be an `id` to look up the `lease` table. Another issue for me is that I don't have `unique ids` already assigned for this. What would be a good way to tackle this?

Comment: How many records are you talking about? You can manually write in the primary keys in your JSON, taking care to match those relationships between tables, then insert the resulting rows by processing that modified JSON. Here's a link to SQLite doc on using INSERT with autoincrement: https://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html

Comment: Not sure how many records will be in there, not many to start with. But, we definitely want scalability in the long run. I think autoincrement is how I will handle this. And when The object is first created, will insert into the other table and reference the autoincrement number. Thanks!